# PHP preg_match UUID v4

Tags: php, preg-match, uuid

I've got a string that contains [UUID v4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959)

```
$uuid = 'http://domain.com/images/123/b85066fc-248f-4ea9-b13d-0858dbf4efc1_small.jpg';
```

How would i get the `b85066fc-248f-4ea9-b13d-0858dbf4efc1` value from the above using `preg_match()`?
More info on UUID v4 can be be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29)

Comment: not sure but try "^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"

Comment: Again, Rufinus, this is wrong, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$uuid = 'http://domain.com/images/123/b85066fc-248f-4ea9-b13d-0858dbf4efc1_small.jpg';
preg_match('!/images/\d+/([a-z0-9\-]*)_!i', $uuid, $m);
```

And

```
preg_match('/[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3‌​}\-[a-f0-9]{12}/', $uuid, $m);
```

works too. Taken from [here](http://nosewheelie.blogspot.com/2006/06/ruby-early-return-considered-harmful.html), but I don't know if we can rely on that.

Comment: No, this regex is waay too permissive.

Comment: The question is how to get the `uuid` from link like that but not from anywhere, e.g. not from text. UUID Definition is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Definition), so I guess my second solution which is, actually, stolen, would work right for this purpose.

Comment: A more strict regex would be `/[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3}\-[a-f0-9]{12}/`

Comment: If the regex doesn't work though it looks correct: there are some invisible characters in the code examples which show up in the html source: &zwnj;&#8203; 

Working version without code highlighting: /[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3}\-[a-f0-9]{12}/

Comment: @ZachMertes The RFC also allows uppercase letters

Answer (score 8):

You can try this simple pattern for uuids

```
preg_match('/\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}/',$uuid,$matches);
```

Comment: This is matching `________-____-____-____-____________`

Comment: Yeah, so don't use this. At least replace \w with [0-9a-f]: '/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/'

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has several flaws:

- It includes hidden characters that break the regex
- It does not allow for uppercase letters (some or all)
- It does not allow for optional dashes

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Textual_representation) for details on allowed representations of a v4 UUID.

A regex check that meets the requirements above is:

```
preg_match(/(?i)[a-f0-9]{8}[\-]?[a-f0-9]{4}[\-]?4[a-f0-9]{3}[\-]?(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3}[\-]?[a-f0-9]{12}/, $uuid, $matches);
```

This option will meet most cases, however a more thorough version would address the following flaws:

- It doesn't allow for the `nil` UUID (all `0`) or the `max` UUID (all `F`)
- It doesn't allow for the Windows-based format that includes leading and trailing braces (`{...}`)

A regex check that meets these requirements as well is:

```
preg_match(/(?i){?[a-f0-9]{8}[\-]?[a-f0-9]{4}[\-]?(4[a-f0-9]{3}|[0]{4}|[F]{4})[\-]?((8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3}|[0]{4}|[F]{4})[\-]?[a-f0-9]{12}}?/, $uuid, $matches);
```

These pieces mean:

- `(?i)`: force case insensitivity
- `{?`: 0 or 1 opening braces
- `[a-f0-9]{8}`: 8 allowed characters
- `[\-]?`: 0 or 1 dashes
- `[a-f0-9]{4}`: 4 allowed characters
- `[\-]?`: 0 or 1 dashes
- `(4[a-f0-9]{3}|[0]{4}|[F]{4})`: a 4 followed by 3 allowed characters, or 4 zeroes, or 4 Fs
- `[\-]?`: 0 or 1 dashes
- `((8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3}|[0]{4}|[F]{4})`: a 4 followed by 3 allowed characters, or 4 zeroes, or 4 Fs
- `[\-]?`: 0 or 1 dashes
- `[a-f0-9]{12}`: 12 allowed characters
- `}?`: 0 or 1 closing braces

For any of you regex wizards out there, this could further be improved if it's possible to do the following:

- Require that if one dash is present, all four dashes must be present
- Only allow all zeroes or all Fs in some blocks if the entire UUID is all zeroes or Fs
- Only allow an opening or closing brace if both are present

Answer (score -3):

When testing if string is matching, then don't forget ^ on beginning and $ on ending in pattern. Without them you can test, if string contains requested string, but not that it match requested string.
'/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/'

Comment: The question is seeking to extract the UUID from the string, the use of ^ and $ around the pattern for the UUID would not match a string that contained the full URL