# Use a default laravel validation rule inside custom rule file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate that my input is either UUID or "LAST_QUESTION". I created a custom validation rule `LastOrUUID` and I would like to use UUID validation rule inside of it. I could not find any way to do that, maybe you know what is the right way to implement this? My custom rule for context:

```
class LastOrUUID implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {

        if ($value === 'LAST_QUESTION' /* || this is uuid */) {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        // TODO - add translation
        return 'This should either be the last question or have a reference to next question!';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think do you mean inherit default validation in you custom class!!!

Comment: @Nazari yes, that would be ideal. But I am pretty happy with at least using `Str::isUuid()`, if it is used by Laravel and there is no better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to validate if the given value is an UUID you can either Laravel's native [`Str::isUuid`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cb398188729f51e63d6fd0dc1ed9009fcf76b404/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L290) method (which uses RegEx under the hood), the [`isValid`](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/ba8fff1d3abb8bb4d35a135ed22a31c6ef3ede3d/src/Uuid.php#L454) method of [Ramsey's UUID package](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) or plain RegEx (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46682530)):

```
// Laravel native
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return $value === 'LAST_QUESTION' || Str::isUuid($value);

// Ramsey's package
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

return $value === 'LAST_QUESTION' || Uuid::isValid($value);

// RegEx
return $value === 'LAST_QUESTION' || preg_match('/[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3‌​}\-[a-f0-9]{12}/', $value);
```

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks for your answer! But my thinking is - if there is a laravel rule, it must have been implemented somehow and should be reusable, no? It would be a good practice to use same UUID validation implementation everywhere where I validate UUID, am I wrong?

Comment: Good thinking! There is indeed a UUID validation rule available. It uses [`Str::isUuid` internally](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cb398188729f51e63d6fd0dc1ed9009fcf76b404/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1771) which again is based [on a RegEx](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cb398188729f51e63d6fd0dc1ed9009fcf76b404/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L290). I'll add that to my post, because I didn't know that Laravel offers this method.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution more. Very helpful.