# How to fix laravel routes?

Tags: php, laravel

Below are my routes, when I try to access `/ranks/weekly`, `ranks/monthly` and `ranks/list` it assume weekly, monthly & list as IDs and request data from GET `/ranks/{id}` `show` function.

```
Route::get('ranks', [RankingController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('ranks', [RankingController::class, 'create']);
Route::get('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'show']);
Route::put('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'destroy']);
Route::get('ranks/list', [RankingController::class, 'plain']);
Route::get('ranks/weekly', [RankingController::class, 'weekly']);
Route::get('ranks/monthly', [RankingController::class, 'monthly']);
```

Comment: Could you try putting ```Route::get('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'show']);``` at the bottom?

Comment: this trick work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason for this is that:

```php
Route::get('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'show']);
```

conflicts with everything succeeding `ranks` (i.e. `weekly` and `monthly`) because that matches with that route too. Like I stated in the comment, you can put the most lenient match at the bottom or be a little bit more restrictive in the matching for example:

```php
Route::get('ranks/{ranking}', [RankingController::class, 'show'])->where('ranking', '[0-9]+');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: and use `/[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-4[a-f0-9]{3}\-(8|9|a|b)[a-f0-9]{3‌​}\-[a-f0-9]{12}/` in case uuid for more detail follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223185/php-preg-match-uuid-v4